Shortest path for multiple points from line layer (optimized path)
I am using QGIS.
I have a set of starting points (blue & red points), and I also have a vector line layer (green line).
I need to find the shortest path from starting point (blue & red points) to line layer (green lines) meeting the below criteria:

If multiple points are coming in the same area all the points to be connected linearly & last point to be connected to line (blue points in below snapshot)
If a point can be connected directly to line without connecting other points shortest path to be drawn.(red points in below snapshot)
The path drawn from lines to be following road network (if possible)

I have tried finding shortest path but this did not resolve as each of the blue point had a separate line till green line




Is there some attribute shared by the points in each blue point group?

All the points will have same attributes , classification of points as Green or Red is based on the position of the points , if point is closer to the green line then its considered as red point & if the point is closer to another point & from that point green line is closer than that cluster of points is considered as blue points. (Blue & Red points are taken only for representation purpose, the application should identify which all points to be directly connected to green line & which all points to be grouped together & the group to be connected to green line). Hope its clear...

May be we can first try to identify which points to be considered as blue & which points to be considered as red & then draw line from them...just a thought

Try DBSCAN clustering to assign grouped or single points cluster ids

I started something based on virtual layers: computing distance from points to lines, searching the furthest point from the line that is within the current's point 'circle to the line'. This should join the blue dots. I know this is not covering all cases, but for some reason it does not work in some cases where it should. I had a similar issue with the geometry generator, where I could get all the red dots to connect, but not all the blue ones. Red points can be points where there is no closer point to the line within the point to line circle
